# Mysql: select previous date from curdate()

Tags: mysql

I need to know which is the record with the date previous to `curdate()`. I dont know how many days or months previous is it.

Really the complete question will be to select the previous date from `curdate()` if `curdate()` its empty.

Now I select the next game but if it is not loaded I dont know how to show still the previous:

```
select * from games where date_game >= curdate() order by date_game limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) from Table) and date < NOW();
```

Comment: Thank..! works great.. I solved with this query
`select * from games where date_game = (SELECT MAX(fecha) from partidos) or date_game >= curdate() order by date_game limit 1;`
with this query I have the next date and if this dont exist, take today or max previous
Thank you..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can select the row that it's `date_column` has lesser value than current date bringing the results in desc order so you pick the one right after the current date.

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE date_column < NOW()
ORDER BY date_column DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: yes its true. but its more useful in my particular case the answer from user3271955. thanks

Comment: No problem. Just to check it, do you have two tables (games, partidos) or only one?

Comment: no. only one table (games)..its my mistake, but I don't know why I can't update my comment.. :(